# Apache POI: clone existing sheet with chart object

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was wondering if anyone using POI has been able to copy a worksheet with a chart object and create another sheet with the chart object intact.
I see here on this forum a similar question:
[Apache POI: cloning worksheets containing charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686891/apache-poi-cloning-worksheets-containing-charts)

BUT, they claim it can't be done, but I had a developer in the past do it, the only problem
was how to change the chart series reference.

Wondering if anyone has tried this with more current versions of Apache POI.

P